# Obtaining the SAS VA Report Name and SAS table name from EG (metadata)

Tags: sas

I've found a snippet of code online to get most of what I need except I'm also looking for the SAS table names that each VA Report uses. Is there a way to do this using data step functions for writing meta data?

```
data MDIDs;
    length Server_Uri rp_uri Metadata_ID Name _Name TypeName Path Location _Location MetadataCreated MetadataUpdated CreatedBy ModifiedBy $256;
    length Created Modified 8.;
    format Created Modified datetime19.;
    nobj = 1;
    n=1;
    call missing(Metadata_ID, _Name, MetadataCreated, MetadataUpdated, Created, Modified, TypeName, Path, Server_Uri, _location, CreatedBy, ModifiedBy);
 
    do while(n le nobj);
        nobj=metadata_getnobj("omsobj:Transformation?@PublicType = 'Report.BI'",n,Server_Uri);
        rc=metadata_getattr(Server_Uri,'Id',Metadata_ID);
        rc=metadata_getattr(Server_Uri,'Name',_Name);
        rc=metadata_getattr(Server_Uri,"MetadataCreated",MetadataCreated);
        rc=metadata_getattr(Server_Uri,"MetadataUpdated",MetadataUpdated);
        name=translate(translate(translate(translate(_name,"-","–"),"£","£"),"%","%"),"+","+");
        Created=input(MetadataCreated,anydtdtm.);
        Modified=input(MetadataUpdated,anydtdtm.);
        rc=metadata_getattr(Server_Uri,"PublicType",TypeName);
        numrp=metadata_getnasn(Server_Uri,"ResponsibleParties",1,rp_uri);
        if numrp>0 then do;
            numrp=metadata_getnasn(Server_Uri,"ResponsibleParties",1,rp_uri);
            rc=metadata_getattr(rp_uri,"name",CreatedBy);
            numrp=metadata_getnasn(Server_Uri,"ResponsibleParties",2,rp_uri);
            rc=metadata_getattr(rp_uri,"name",ModifiedBy);
        end;

        TreesCount=metadata_getnasn(Server_Uri,"Trees",1,Server_Uri);
        rc=metadata_getattr(Server_Uri,"Name",Path);
        _tree=1;
        do while (_tree>0);
            _tree=metadata_getnasn(Server_Uri,"ParentTree",1,Server_Uri);
            if _tree > 0 then do;
                _rc=metadata_getattr(Server_Uri,"Name",_location);
                Path=catx('/',_location,Path);
            end;
        end;

        Location = '/'||Path;
        output;
        n=n+1;
    end;

    keep Metadata_ID Name TypeName Location Created Modified CreatedBy ModifiedBy;

run;
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this depending on your version. SAS 9.4 uses the Metadata server and parsing using SAS, while SAS Viya uses APIs.

### SAS 9.4

The metadata server will not tell you which data the VA report uses in SAS 9.4, but you can extract the report XML and parse it to find all of the data sources. When you pull the content from the report file on the metadata server, you'll get XML.

All of the data sources fall under the `<DataSources>` tag. For example, here we have two tables loaded to LASR: CARS and CLASS.

```
<DataSources>
    <DataSource label="CARS" type="relational" name="ds7">
        <InMemoryResource resourceName="SBIP://METASERVER/Shared Data/LASR/AUTOLOAD/CARS(table)" label="AUTOLOAD.CARS"/>
        <BusinessItemFolder>
            ...
        </BusinessItemFolder>
    </DataSource>
    <DataSource label="CLASS" type="relational" name="ds19">
        <InMemoryResource resourceName="SBIP://METASERVER/Shared Data/LASR/AUTOLOAD/CLASS(Table)" label="AUTOLOAD.CLASS"/>
        <BusinessItemFolder>
            ...
        </BusinessItemFolder>
    </DataSource>
</DataSources>
```

You can extract this with SAS.

```
data want;
    infile "/path/to/file/report.xml" lrecl=32676 length=len;
    input line $varying32767. len;

    if(find(upcase(line), '<DATASOURCE LABEL='));

    table = scan(line, 2, '"');

    drop line;
run;
```

```
table
CARS
CLASS
```

### SAS Viya

You can use the Viya REST API to get the report XML and parse it in a similar way. The only difference is you'll also need to obtain the CASLIB. You'll need the report URI, which you can get from either SAS Drive or by copying a link to the report. The URI looks like a GUID, like this:

`fc0331a6-311h-4267-84d8-512ec2ff375d`

You can get the XML by going to the `/content` endpoint of the Reports service. For example:

`https://myviyaserver.com/reports/reports/fc0331a6-311h-4267-84d8-512ec2ff375d/content`

If you want to find every report URI on the system by name, you can get a JSON file by going to `/reports/reports/?limit=999999`. Keep in mind, setting it to a very high limit like this will return a *lot* of data if you have a lot of reports, so try setting it to a low value first and then test it. If you do not give it any options, it will default to 20 which is a good starting point.

`https://myviyaserver.com/reports/reports`

**JSON Output**

```
{
 "links": [
    ...
 ],

  "name": "reports",
  "accept": "application/vnd.sas.summary",
  "start": 0,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "fc0331a6-311h-4267-84d8-512ec2ff375d",
      "name": "My Dashboard",
      "createdBy": "person@company.com",
      "creationTimeStamp": "2024-02-13T13:17:53.169Z",
      "modifiedBy": "person@company.com",
      "modifiedTimeStamp": "2024-02-15T09:39:13.190Z",
      "links": [
      ...
      ]
   },
   {
      "id": "ac019za6-421h-81d8-4c12-916ea235379d",
      "name": "My Other Dashboard",
      "createdBy": "person@company.com",
      "creationTimeStamp": "2024-02-22T16:51:03.960Z",
      "modifiedBy": "person@company.com",
      "modifiedTimeStamp": "2024-02-23T15:43:42.874Z",
      "links": [
      ...
      ]
   },
   ...
```

You can do this all in SAS Studio with `PROC HTTP` and a small change to the data step.

```
filename resp temp;
    
proc http
    url="https://%scan(&_baseurl, -2, /)/reports/reports/fc0331a6-311h-4267-84d8-512ec2ff375d/content" 
    out=resp
    method='get'
    oauth_bearer=SAS_SERVICES;
run;
    
data want;
    infile resp lrecl=32676 length=len;
    input line $varying32767. len;
    
    if(find(upcase(line), '<CASRESOURCE'));
    
    caslib = scan(line, 4, '"');
    table  = scan(line, 6, '"');
    
    keep caslib table;
run;
```

**Loop through every Visual Analytics report in Viya and get the data sources**

Here's the entire code to go through a list of reports and get their data, then save it to a single file.

```
filename resp1 temp; * Response for JSON report list;
filename resp2 temp; * Response for XML;

%let limit = 20; *Limit the number of returned reports;

/* Get reports */
proc http
    url="https://%scan(&_baseurl, -2, /)/reports/reports?limit=&limit" 
    out=resp1
    method='get'
    oauth_bearer=SAS_SERVICES;
run;

libname reports json "%sysfunc(pathname(resp1))";

/* Save every report name and ID to a macro variable */
data _null_;
    set reports.items;

    call symputx(cats('id', _N_), id);
    call symputx(cats('name', _N_), name);
    call symputx('n_reports', _N_);
run;

/* Loop through every ID and macro variable, pull its XML and get its data sources */
%macro get_report_data;

    proc datasets lib=work nolist;
        delete report_data;
    quit;

    %do i = 1 %to &n_reports;
        %let id = &&id&i;
        %let name = &&name&i;
    
        /* Wait a few seconds between each attempt */
        %let rc = %sysfunc(sleep(3, 1));

        proc http
            url="https://%scan(&_baseurl, -2, /)/reports/reports/&id/content" 
            out=resp2
            method='get'
            oauth_bearer=SAS_SERVICES;
        run;

        data tmp;
            length name $100. id caslib table $50.;

            infile resp2 lrecl=32676 length=len;
            input line $varying32767. len;
    
            if(find(upcase(line), '<CASRESOURCE'));
    
            name   = "&name";
            id     = "&id";
            caslib = scan(line, 4, '"');
            table  = scan(line, 6, '"');
    
            drop line;
        run;

        proc append base=report_data data=tmp;
        run;
    %end;
%mend;
%get_report_data;
```

```
name                 id                                      caslib  table
My Dashboard         fc0331a6-311h-4267-84d8-512ec2ff375d    PUBLIC  CARS
My Other Dashboard   ac019za6-421h-81d8-4c12-916ea235379d    PUBLIC  CLASS
```